# How i Post Data on server with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, cordova

I am using HTML5.
I want to Call API with AJAX. but, not success to perform this. plz Help me how i Use this.
I want Implement this code PhoneGap. Plz suggest me if any issue or best logic...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
alert("okey");
  $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url:'http://www.internationalprom.com/mobile/ipa.php',
  data:{ft:'get',cat:'gallery',action:'top100'},
  success: onsuccess,
  error : onerror,


});
function onsuccess(data){
alert("success 1: "+ data );
// if got success then How i retrive Data from here?


}

function onerror(data){
alert("error 1 :"+data);
}

}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h2>My CD Collection:</h2>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks...

Comment: did you add your url to phonegap whitelist?! post your log please

Comment: @Ocelot When make phonegap Whitelist enable then work properly. thanks Cheers...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to POST data you need to use HTTP POST not HTTP GET and also call `json.stringify()` on the JSON like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'http://www.internationalprom.com/mobile/ipa.php',
    data: JSON.stringify({ft:'get',cat:'gallery',action:'top100'}),
    success: onsuccess,
    error : onerror
});
```

Comment: thanks for Quick reply... but, I check my old code and new code both.. both have same response....

Comment: Chrome and Firefox have got response "status" is always "0" 
But, in Safari i have got response ""status" is "200"

Comment: @MRT are you getting this response status in success or error, or is it just firing complete?

Comment: @Dinev i getting response status in success but this is always "0". when i use on "Chrome" and "Mozila firefox"
But, When i work or Safari this response Status is "200" in success.

Comment: Hey working properly My and your code both r fine But when i make sure Whitelist done then work properly... Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know what info the server returns, but not the format.
The data the server returns is a JSON string (JavaScript Object Notation).
On the internet there are plenty of tutorials how to parse that, simplest is `eval(JSONstring)` but if you search Stackoverflow you'll find questions about eval called [`When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197769/1087848) and so on. That may give an idea about how recommended it is.
Hope this helps you!